# How can I reduce the garbage generation in this situation

Tags: c#, garbage-collection, slimdx

My game has gotten to the point where its generating too much garbage and is resulting in long GC times.  I've been going around and reducing a lot of the garbage generated but there's one spot that's allocating a large amount of memory too frequently and I'm stuck on how I can resolve this.

My game is a minecraft-type world that generates new regions as you walk.  I have a large, variable size array that is allocated on the creation of a new region that is used to store the vertex data for the terrain.  After the array is filled with data, it's passed to a slimdx DataStream so it can be used for rendering.

The problem is the fact that this is a variable-size array and that it needs to be passed to slimdx, which calls GCHandle.Alloc on it.  Since its a variable size, it may have to be resized in order to reuse it.  I also can't just allocate a max sized array for each region because it would require impossibly large amounts of memory.  I can't use a List because of the GCHandle business with slimdx.

So far, resizing the array only when it needs to be made bigger seems to be the only plausible option to me, but it may not work out that well and will likely be a pain to implement.  I'd need to keep track of the actual size of the array separately and use unsafe code to get a pointer to the array and pass that to slimdx.  It may also end up eventually using such a large amount of memory that I have to occasionally go and reduce the size of all the arrays down to the minimum needed.

I'm hesitant to jump at this solution and would like to know if anyone sees any better solutions to this.

Comment: Are you sure it is the array creation only? Does the array contain class objects or structs? If it does contain classes it might be that you did create a big and complex object graph which will take the GC much longer to check for garbage.

Comment: Its an array of structs.  The struct contains 3 structs (Vector3) and 2 floats.  The CLR profiler allocation graph lists this struct as the largest offender, at almost 300MB (25%).

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest a tighter integration with the slimdx library.  It's open source so you could dig in and find the critical path that you need for the rendering.  Then you could integrate tighter by using a DMA-style memory sharing approach.

Comment: Well slimdx lets you create a DataStream in 3 ways: Pass it a size and it allocates a backing store, pass it an array and it uses that, or pass it a pointer.  Since I'm already using the array method, isn't that already memory sharing?

Comment: Look into it a little a make sure that the library is not doing something weird like copying half the array to another array as soon as you pass it.  And then de-allocating that half-size temp array and causing a lot of garbage.

Comment: Also, it seems excessive for a terrain vertex map to take 300MB.  There must be sparseness that you could take advantage of if you isolate the critical path for rendering only and remove any checking by slimdx of the other parts of the structure, and then remove those from the structure.

Comment: In some of the more mountainous regions, where the stuttering is worst, there can be up to 2.8 million vertices loaded for the terrain.  Each vertex takes 44 bytes.  When moving quickly, the game is loading about 15MB per second.  The 300MB was over the course of about 20s or so.

Comment: Also, regarding slimdx doing any kind of weird allocating stuff:  there are only 2 classes involved in this, DataStream and Buffer.  I commented out the creation of the Buffer and stuttering was still present.  I looked at the code of DataStream and confirmed that with the overload I'm using, it doesn't allocate anything.

Comment: I may be old school, but that still seems like a lot of detail.  Isn't there some way you could 'synthesize' some of the textures randomly?  Like instead of having thousands of points describe the side of a mountain, you can just have concept that this fractal function defines a particular area.   This reminds me of video compression.  A well established way to reduce the size of filmed video is to reduce the detail in fast moving areas.  The human eye is much less likely to notice blockiness if the object moves past quickly.

Comment: Well if your familiar with minecraft type worlds, they're entirely made up of cubes.  The terrain is generated on the fly, randomly.  I don't see some easy way to reduce the detail without massively changing the design of the engine.

Answer (score 1):

Since SlimDX is open source and it is too slow the time has come to change the open Source to suit your performance needs. What I do see here is that you want to keep a much larger array but hand to SlimDX only the actual used region to prevent additional memory allocatons for this potentially huge array.

There is a type in the .NET Framework named [ArraySegment](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1hsbd92d.aspx) which was made exactly for this purpose.

```
// Taken from MSDN
// Create and initialize a new string array.
String[] myArr = { "The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", 
                   "lazy", "dog" };

// Define an array segment that contains the middle five values of the array.
ArraySegment<String> myArrSegMid = new ArraySegment<String>( myArr, 2, 5 );


public static void PrintIndexAndValues( ArraySegment<String> arrSeg )  
{
   for ( int i = arrSeg.Offset; i < (arrSeg.Offset + arrSeg.Count); i++ )  
   {
        Console.WriteLine( "   [{0}] : {1}", i, arrSeg.Array[i] );
   }
   Console.WriteLine();
}
```

That said I have found the usage of ArraySegment somewhat strange because I always have to use the offset and the index which just behaves not a regular array. Instead you can distill your own struct which allows zero based indexing which is much easier to use but comes at the cost that every index based access does cost you and add of the base offset. But if the usage pattern is mainly foreaches then it does not really matter.

I had situations where ArraySegment was also too costly because you do allocate a struct every time and pass it to all methods by value on the stack. You need to watch closely where its usage is ok and if it is not allocated at a too high rate.

Answer (score 0):

I sympathize your problem with older library, slimdx, which may not be .NET compliant. I have dealt with such a situation.

Suggestions:

1. Use a more performance efficient generic list or array like ArrayList. It keeps track of the size of the array so you don't have to. Allocate the List, chunks at a time, e.g. 100 elements at a time.
2. Use C++ .NET and take advantage of unsafe arrays or the .NET classes like ArrayList.
3. **Updated**: Use the idea of virtual memory. Save some data to an XML file or SQL database, relieving huge amount of memory.

I realize it's a gamble either way.

Comment: I can't use a generic .net class that auto-resizes.  Upon resizing, the data will be copied to a new memory address without me knowing and slimdx will still point to the old location.  I don't see how c++ .net would help with this.

Comment: With C++, your code can use unsafe types and pointers, and you can pass addresses to slimdx functions. But you still have to manage the memory yourself.

Comment: Use the idea of virtual memory, as I added to my list of suggestions above. I know this adds code but it is not a software redesign.

Comment: I can't really use virtual memory for this.  All of the data is needed for rendering so it has to stay in memory.  Anything outside of the players view is unloaded right now, so it's not like out-of-view regions are using any memory.